# Firebase cloud function testing with emulator instead of cloud

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing#initializing) for creating cloud function testing directs the user to configure the test suite.
Here's the code block it directs the user to create:

```
// At the top of test/index.test.js
const test = require('firebase-functions-test')({
  databaseURL: 'https://my-project.firebaseio.com',
  storageBucket: 'my-project.appspot.com',
  projectId: 'my-project',
}, 'path/to/serviceAccountKey.json');
```

We wish to use online mode, but we wish to test against the local firebase emulator instead of a cloud instance. We attempted to initialize the test by omitting the key file and redirecting the database url as below:

```
require('firebase-functions-test')({
        databaseURL: 'localhost:9000',
        storageBucket: 'my-project.appspot.com',
        projectId: 'my-project',
    });
```

Unfortunately this does not work. The program will just throw the exception:

> @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: {"code":"app/invalid-credential","message":"Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: "Error fetching access token: Error while making request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND metadata.google.internal. Error code: ENOTFOUND"."}

How is a user supposed to hookup to an emulator rather than a cloud instance?

Comment: Check [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@timo.santi/jest-testing-firebase-functions-with-emulator-suite-409907f31f39), it looks similar and might give you insights how to implement this.